# Solving a second order generalized homogenous ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$x^4(y'^2 - 2yy'') = 4x^3yy' + 1$$

I tried approaching this as a generalized homogenous equation. The trick is to substitute $x=kx$ and $y = k^my$, $y' = k^{m-1}y'$, $y'' = k^{m-2}y''$, $m \in \mathbb{R}$

After substituting, every term in the above equation needs to have the same power of $k$. From there, we calculate the parameter $m$ by equating the powers of $k$ in all terms.

$$k^{2m-2}y'^2 \cdot k^4x^4 - 2k^my \cdot k^{m-2}y'' \cdot k^4x^4 = 4k^3x^3 \cdot k^my \cdot k^{m-1}y'+1$$

It's obvious that $$2m+2=2m+2=2m+2=0$$ which means that $m=-1$.

Now we make the substitution $x=e^t$, $y=z(t)e^{mt}$

$$\dot{y}=e^{-t}(\dot{z}-z)$$

$$\ddot{y}=e^{-t}(\ddot{z}+z-2\dot{z})$$

While $$y' = \frac{\dot{y}}{\dot{x}}$$

and $$y'' = \frac{ \ddot{y} \dot{x} - \dot{y} \dot{x}}{\dot{x}^3}$$

When I plug the $\dot{y}$, $\ddot{y}$, $\dot{x}$, $\ddot{x}$, I get that

$$y'' = \frac{\ddot{z} + 2z - 3\dot{z}}{e^{3t}}$$

$$y' = e^{-2t}(\dot{z}-z)$$

When I plug this into my original equation, the exponential terms cancel out and I get

$$z' - z - 2zz'' + 2zz' - 1 = 0 $$

However, this equation I cannot solve, and neither can WolframAlpha.

Where did I go wrong? I think I did everything correct because the exponential terms cancel out nicely (which is what they're supposed to do when I find such a number $m$).

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

$$x^4(y'^2 - 2yy'') = 4x^3yy' + 1$$
$$y=\frac z {x^2} \implies 2 z z''-z'^2+1=0$$  Try a series solution to get a very simple answer.

Comment: Or separate first to get logarithmic derivatives, $\dfrac{2z'z''}{z'^2-1}=\dfrac{z'}{z}$.

Comment: @LutzLehmann. Still better !